# Change class of dynamically generated components in REACT without manually creating a separate state for each?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to change the style of dynamically generated components when they are being clicked, but just one at the time. I could not find an answer that worked for my code.

The generated components :

```js
<Col>
  {ageCategoriesDisplay.map((category) => (
   <h3
      key={category}
      onClick={(() => categoryCheckHandler(category), ToggleClass)}
   >
   {category}
   </h3>
))}
</Col>
```

Please do not mind categoryCheckHandler, it is related to something else. ToggleClass is empty at the moment.

So you see I am trying to toggle the class of the clicked component, but I do not know how to grab this specific component and and toggle its class. All the answers I found tell me to use state, but I cannot create manually a state for each of these components as their number and name will often vary, and if I use only one state obviously they all toggle when when one is clicked.

I have found some answers using the "old" way of doing things in react, with the constructor and "this", but I am not familiar with this way of doing things, I work with hooks. Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a child component.

```
ageCategoriesDisplay.map(item => (
   <ChildComponent useWhenChange={ runsomefunction } item={item}/>
)
```

You can use this item in the loop and it auto create as many item as your category has.

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

    const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState({ fontSize: '1rem'})
    const [ addClass, setAddClass ] = useState(false);

    const onClickFunction = () => {
        setAddClass(true)
        setSomeState({ fontSize: '2rem' })
        props.useWhenChange() // <-- also can call parent function
    }
    return ( <div><h1 onClick={onClickFunction} className={ addClass ? 'somecssClass' : ''} style={someState}>Click Me To Change Size</h1>
             {/* you can also render the props e.g. name */}
             <h2>{props.item.name}</div>
             </div>
}
```

above demonstrate **Calling parent function**, **toggling a class** base on true/false, **rendering the .map item** and **setting the style**.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this !